# Do I check the existence of a macro function with or without the parens?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, ifndef

Before I define a macro function, I can check that it doesn't already exist
(this avoids overwriting a previous definition).

I can implement the check and definition like this:

```
#ifndef MACRO(X)
#define MACRO(X) FUNCTION(X)
#endif
```

Or like this:

```
#ifndef MACRO
#define MACRO(X) FUNCTION(X)
#endif
```

Both appear to work when the function is already defined.
So, which is correct?  Which is preferred?

Comment: I'd leave off the parens/parameter.

Comment: The second one is correct. The first one is undefined behaviour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without.

The standard specifies that `#ifndef` is equivalent to `#if !defined`, and that the argument to `defined` must be a (possibly parenthesized) *identifier*. You can't have parens in an identifier, so `defined MACRO(X)` is not an allowed form. This use of `defined` causes undefined behaviour, so it is not portable.

Answer (score 2):

Without parentheses.  Because of this reason:

**test.c**

```
#ifdef MACRO(x)
#endif
int main() {}
```

If you try to compile this:

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c:2:13: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive [enabled by default]
 #ifdef MACRO(x)
             ^
```

It gives a warning.